# How do I run the test cases in a non-web-project I have imported into my Spring web project?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven-2, junit

This package has a class - [HowToUseGeocell.java](http://code.google.com/p/javageomodel/source/browse/#svn/trunk/geocell/src/test/java/com/beoui/utils) - with test cases defined.

I have imported this entire project into a larger Java web project (Spring 3) in Eclipse controlled by a Maven task (`gae:run`).

But I don't know how to run these test cases from inside the larger project.

Could someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have imported this entire project into a larger Java web project

If this means that the sources and tests of the "non web project" have been copied respectively in the `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` trees of the "web project", then just run:

```
mvn test
```

If the import is about something else, please explain what it means and what the project structure looks like.